# Set default date in ngbdatepicker - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to set value for the datepicker input control value using angular reactive forms formscontrol but still failing to assign the default value.

```
<label id='lbl-from-date'> FROM DATE</label>
              <div class="input-group">       
                <input  autocomplete="off" formControlName="fromDate" id='inp-from-date' type="text" class="form-control"
                  name="dp" ngbAutofocus ngbDatepicker #lastMonthStartDate="ngbDatepicker" >

                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button id="btn-from-date" class="flight-calender btn btn-outline-secondary calendar"
                    (click)="lastMonthStartDate.toggle()" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Tried to set the value from the formobject as below

Method 1:

```
this.formObj.setValue({
      fromDate: null,
      endDate: null

    });
```

Method 2:

```
 this.formObj.get('fromDate').setValue(this.pastMonthDates.fromDate.toString());
```

both the methods didn't worked, also tried several other ways.

And tried to set the value with id/binding in input control but the value is not get setting.

Regards,
Pk

Comment: try this `const defaultDate = { year: 2022, month: 3, day: 1 };
this.formObj.get('fromDate').setValue(defaultDate);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are passing a valid date object to the `fromDate` control like this:

```
const defaultDate = { year: 2022, month: 3, day: 1 };
this.formObj.get('fromDate').setValue(defaultDate);
```